# How To Interpret E+ or E- Notation in Curves of Best Fit?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, curves, scientific-notation, desmos

I have some data which I plotted using google sheets. I came up with a curve of best fit which was a degree 4 polynomial. The equation I got was:

9E+08 + 1.86E+06x + - 1397x^2 + 0.467x^3 - 5.85E-05x^4

I assumed that E used in this context meant 9*10^8 or 1.86*10^6 -5.85*10^-5 but when I graph that curve in desmos it looks nothing like the curve of best fit Google Sheets came up with. I think I'm interpreting the E incorrectly. Can someone please tell me how I should be interpreting that E notation? Or more precisely, can someone please tell me what this curve should be using scientific notation rather than E?

A screenshot of the actual graph is below:

[image]

Data Table:

Years   Conservatives PV

2019,   34.3

2015,   31.9

2011,   39.6

2008,   37.6

2006,   36.3

2004,   29.6

2000,   12.2

1997,   18.8

1993,   16

1988,   43

1984,   50

1980,   32.5

1979,   35.9

1974,   35.4

1972,   35

1968,   31.4

1965,   32.1

The Desmos graph here looks entirely different and is very tall. Why is that?

The equation I'm graphing is: $$-9.27\cdot10^{8}+1.86\cdot10^{6}x-1397x^{2}+0.467x^{3}-5.85\cdot10^{-5}x^{4}$$

[image]

Comment: can you include the pictures and and the data point? how do you obtain the polynomials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the $E$ means multiply by $10$ to the power.  You have omitted a minus sign on the constant term.  This polynomial is computed by multiplying very small numbers and very big numbers and adding them up, so it is very sensitive to the coefficients.  Try getting more precise coefficients (more digits) before plotting in desmos.  What you have so far is
$$-9.27\cdot10^{8}+1.86\cdot10^{6}x-1397x^{2}+0.467x^{3}-5.85\cdot10^{-5}x^{4}$$

Comment: Thanks, @RobPratt If you try to graph this function in desmos though, with the same scale I see a totally different curve. Why is that happening? I'll add this to my original question.

Comment: Did you use more precise coefficients?

Comment: I used the exact same coefficients in your reply. I've added it in my original post. Do you see different behaviour when you graph it in Desmos?

Comment: The formula I gave was just in the format desmos expects, but you need to use more precise coefficients to get the same plot as Google Sheets.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks very much.